# Could not get any response - Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, owin

I have a .NET MVC Project and I am using API controllers inside the project for REST API's. Authentication used in the project is based on OwinMiddleware.

The following piece of code is used in OwinMiddleware for authentication

```
 var authValue = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authValue) && (authValue.StartsWith("Basic ")))
  {
      authValue = authValue.Substring(6).Trim();
      authValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authValue));
      var credentials = authValue.Split(":".ToCharArray());
      var signInStatus = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(credentials[0], credentials[1], false, false);

          switch (signInStatus)
           {
             case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Success:
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(credentials[0]);
                    var identity = await _signinManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);
                    context.Request.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                     await base.Next.Invoke(context);
                     break;

             default:
                   context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
// an aobject representing error
                   var res = GetResposeData() 
                   var format = GetResponseContentType(context.Request);
                   var data = ParseToString(res , format);
                   var dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                  context.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(format);
                  context.Response.Body.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);
                   break;
             }

    }
```

In the startup.cs I have added the following code

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomSignInManager>());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomUserManager>());
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/index"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                }
            }
        });
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(AutofacConfig.Container);
    }
```

When I call API continuously using postman the following response was found

**Could not get any response.
There was an error connecting to baseUrl/api/User?pageNumber=1&pageSize=500.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General**

The following are some exceptions from the Windows event log.

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 2/14/2019 7:04:10 PM  Event time (UTC): 2/14/2019 8:04:10
>   AM  Event ID: 22548ff89e3744adbfd5c3e2b3b66ef4  Event sequence: 5 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/XYZ-2-131946050074629312 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /XYZ 
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\ 
>       Machine name: ABC    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 15228 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpException 
>       Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.    at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String
>   name, String value, Boolean replace)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String
>   key, String[] values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2
>   headers, String key, String[] values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext
>   context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

API controller have the following code to return the response

```
   // create new response
// format can be json or xml
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, format),
                StatusCode = httpStatus
            };

            //if last modified available
// some date value
            if (lastUpdated != null)
                response.Content.Headers.LastModified = lastUpdated; 

            return response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up webapi and MVC authentication. Change your code startup.cs to below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomSignInManager>());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomUserManager>());
        app.MapWhen((context) => {
                return !IsApiRequest(context.Request);                
            }, (mvcApp) => {
                mvcApp.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/index"),
                    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
                });
            });
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(AutofacConfig.Container);
    }
```